# One click get modal image

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i trying to make script for example: 
I get images from id of sql table and i got list images

Image1      |    Image2    |  Image3   .......

i try to make when i click Image1 show me this image in modal. i have example script but when i click image2 i cant get image and click. just working for Image1 
Any help ?

My example Script:

Call The Function : ->

```
<img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["image"]; ?>" style="max- 
           width:100px;max-height:75px;" id="myImg"></div>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
```

Javascript Function - >

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

CSS Style:

```
<style>

#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */

}

.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

.close {
    background:red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 63px;
    right: 275px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
```

And how i Put another images to same id with example this:

Image1   |   Image2   |  Image3

I click  Image1 and get modal and down side in modal show me (1),2,3 images more for this Image1 and when i click (2) just stay in modal and change this image for id Image1 and second image for this...  Maybe any one understand me. Sorry for my language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open same model in each image click then please use `class` instead of using `id`.
Or if you want to open different model on each image click then you have to create separate model containing id like myModal1 , myModal2, .. and Image id like myImg1, myImg2, ..
After that, you have to write code which is detect the number of image click , based on that number you have to open model.